# how get the name of a file that generates an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

How can I get name of file that generates exception.

ex.
addUser.aspx

```
try
{ 
    SaveUser(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    response.wrhite(ex.GETPAGE().toString());
}

return addUser.aspx;
```

Comment: Where is that code running? I assume it's not in the addUser.aspx.cs file?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is is inside AddUser, I need save in a LogTable the page address

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You must already know where `SaveUser` is. Which page are you looking for? The page that called `AddUser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Exception` class does not have any information regarding what you are looking for. [As Yahia notes here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841723/237838), you can get the class name from the Exception, but as you have found, that does not really help for finding the ASPX path.

The best thing to do is to use the `Request.Url.ToString()` method from inside your exception handler, as [Graham notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841724/237838). Since your code is running from inside the ASPX.cs related to your page, the `Request` object is available for this.

Answer (score 2):

For C# in ASP.NET, you can get it via the Request object during the Application_Error event in the Global.asax.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// some code here
String url = Request.Url.ToString()
// some more code here
}
```

Comment: I need get the page using Exception class

Comment: @soamazing The `Exception` class does not contain anything that gives you the ASPX page that was being executed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber so you can answer this, in the post?

Comment: +1 to this answer since I sort of stole a reference to it in my own.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the file but the `class` is available in [`ex.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.source.aspx).

You can access the URL of the current request with [`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx).

Comment: Source returns App_Web_dnpzvfs8

Comment: I need to get the current page inside the Class that receives the exception value (ex)

Comment: +1 to this answer since I sort of stole a reference to it in my own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an UGLY-ASS answer, which I don't recommend:

The StaceTrace has the page file name IF the exception is coming from the actual page (and not a DLL or other class somewhere else in the project). Here's the trace of a simple page and method that throws for me locally:

```
at WebApp2.ExceptionPage.BlowUp() in C:\Users\gpeel\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GPTestBed\WebApp2\Exception.aspx.cs:line 27 at WebApp2.ExceptionPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\gpeel\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GPTestBed\WebApp2\Exception.aspx.cs:line 16
```

You could tease out that file name by looking for the first instance of the phrase '.aspx.cs', then going left in the string til you get to the first "\" character. That would give you "Exception.aspx.cs" from the above.

I strongly urge you to re-do your code to work off the Exception object in the Application_Error even of global.asax though. Called *Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()* in that event to get the exception that threw, and *Request.Url* to get the page.